# google map app - can't successfully create a simple map app

Tags: android

I seem to be having some problems with google connection authorization while trying to set up my google map app sample it show me a gray screen with zooming options but no + or -, here's the logcat:

```
11-23 16:01:46.811: E/Google Maps Android API(19391): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
11-23 16:01:46.821: E/Google Maps Android API(19391): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.zpot3, API Key: AIzaSyA6Z5FOsq1XD-9Ui6HHZ7FN0pH8sX3cwUI, Certificate Fingerprint: ED6E2DCAC367F47AB12DC92559E5C148CE8376BB
11-23 16:01:46.831: I/Google Maps Android API(19391): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
11-23 16:01:51.396: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4bc42000 size:19845120 offset:18493440
11-23 16:01:51.396: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4e6c2000 size:6021120 offset:4669440
11-23 16:01:51.406: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4ec80000 size:12103680 offset:10752000
11-23 16:01:57.232: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(19391): <ConfigWindowMatch:2089>: Format RGBX_8888.
11-23 16:01:57.242: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4bc42000 size:6021120 offset:4669440 fd:96
11-23 16:01:57.312: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4c34a000 size:13455360 offset:12103680 fd:105
11-23 16:01:57.382: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4bc42000 size:6021120 offset:4669440
11-23 16:01:57.382: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x4c34a000 size:13455360 offset:12103680
11-23 16:02:02.016: E/Google Maps Android API(19391): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
11-23 16:02:06.010: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(19391): <ConfigWindowMatch:2089>: Format RGBX_8888.
11-23 16:02:06.020: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4bc42000 size:13578240 offset:12226560 fd:96
11-23 16:02:06.080: D/memalloc(19391): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4ca7f000 size:6021120 offset:4669440 fd:105
```

Comment: Add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> to your manifest

Comment: ok that fixed half the problem, now I dont see the map, just a gray screen with + and - (zoom for the map).

Comment: Okay! Check if your API Key is correct or noot. And update ur question with the new logcat error

Comment: Done, checking my api code now

Comment: Did you add this into your `Manifest` : `<permission
        android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />`.

Comment: Did you put the SHA key then semicolon then your package name while creating the key in console.

Answer (score 0):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and **make sure that generate api key with package name which is mentioned in android manifest file and your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.**

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

After got this let me know.

Comment: I got the right api code im sure, and still I have gray screen, what now?

Comment: Yes I did and still.... nothing :X 
in my google api console it show me:
 Google Maps Android API v2  - ON.
Check out my new logcat for further details

Comment: are you generated api key by using package name which is mentioned in manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

And make sure following steps done correct or not:

Steps:
* to ensure that device has Google Play services APK
* to install Google Play Service rev. more than 2

[image]

- to create project at https://code.google.com/apis/console/
- to enable "Google Maps Android API v2"
  [image]
- to register of SHA1 in project (**NOW, YOU NEED WRITE SHA1;your.app.package.name**) at APIs console and get API KEY
- to copy directory ANDROID_SDK_DIR/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib to root of your project
- to add next line to the YOUR_PROJECT/project.properties

`android.library.reference.1=google-play-services_lib`

- to add next lines to the YOUR_PROJECT/proguard-project.txt

`-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {`

`protected Object[][] getContents();`

`}`

Okay, now you ready to create your own Google Map app with using Google Map APIs V2 for Android.

If you create application with min SDK = 8, please use android support library v4 + SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.